# Getting the wrong result subtracting a Date&Time from another Date&Time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I am trying to subtract a date/time in cell Format Custom: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM. from another time in the same format.
I have tried ideas from so many websites as to how to do it but none show an example of how I wish it done.
have tried using DATEDIF formulas, formulas with TIMEVALUE with MINUTE(TIME(HOUR and many more and nothing works .... so
Let's say
A1 = 11-25-2020  3:30:00 PM
A2 = 09-16-2020  7:30:00 AM
and
A3 = SUM(A1-A2) = 00/03/10 08:00:00
A3 is formatted yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

A1 when converted to general = 44160.64583
A2 when converted to general = 44090.3125
A3 when converted to general = 70.33333333
So the date/time to number conversion looks right
and the math looks right
The issue is with the conversion of number to Date/Time in A3.

Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance
Curt

Comment: What are your expecting the answer to look like? The date for time code 70.3 is indeed 10 March 1900. That is 70 days since 1 Jan 1900. In my mind, once you subtract two dates from each other, the result is purely a number in days. Formatting it as a date does not help much. What you could  do is display it as eg. "10 W 1 D 12 H" (=71.5)

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about this problem?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to be the difference between the 2 Date/Times I see when it posted it did not come out looking like I expected. but I want the answer to be yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss 00/02/09 08:00:00 but it yeilds an answer of 00/03/10 08:00:00

Comment: Hi there, what I want to do ( but not for the purpose used in the example) is for instance I know the year, month, day, hour, minute and second My daughter was born and I want excel to subtract it from the current year, month, day, hour, minute and second and give me the difference in year, month, day, hour, minute and second. Is there no way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, of course, is that neither years nor months have a fixed number of days, so the differences need to be calculated individually.

To output the values as a string, you can try:

```
=TEXT(DATEDIF(A2,A1,"y"),"[<>1]0 ""yrs,""; 0 ""yr,""")&
  TEXT(DATEDIF(A2,A1,"ym"),"[<>1] 0 ""months,""; 0 ""month,""") &
  TEXT(DATEDIF(A2,A1,"md")-(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(A1,1)),"[<>1] 0 ""days,"";0 ""day, """) &
  TEXT(HOUR(MOD(A1,1)-MOD(A2,1)+(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(A1,1))),"[<>1] 0 ""hrs,""; 0 ""hr,""") &
  TEXT(MINUTE(MOD(A1,1)-MOD(A2,1)+(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(A1,1))),"[<>1] 0 ""mins,""; 0 ""min""") &
  TEXT(SECOND(MOD(A1,1)-MOD(A2,1)+(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(A1,1))),"[<>1] 0 ""secs""; 0 ""sec""")
```

Note that we use the Boolean `(MOD(A2,1)>MOD(A1,1))` to determine whether to add/subtract a day from the day and time values to account for an ending time being before a starting time.

[image]

If you want a different output format, that is doable.  But I would stick with output as **text*, because certain differences cannot be expressed with the date format; for example `01-02-29` (`1 yr, 2 months, 29 days`) since there were not 29 days in February that year).

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much Ron, Unfortunately advanced Excel isn't my forte. I really appreciate this - Curt

Comment: Hmmmm sorry to br a PITA but not quite perfect, as I was going to sleep last night I had a thought and just got to testing it now and as I feared in certain conditions it returns the wrong data, for instance if we change A1 to 01/01/2022 6:00:00 AM and A2 to 01/01/2020 12:00:00 PM the results are off, do you think this can be fixed? I cannot believe how difficult something that I thought would be simple is.

Comment: @Curt It's not  **"wrong"**. It's just not in a desirable format.  After all `0 months, **-**1 days, 18hrs`  is the same as `11 months,30 days, 18 hrs`.  If you need not only accuracy, but also the format, I'd suggest you develop a VBA solution. It'll be simpler in the long run.  The problem has to do with how the `DATEDIF` function has limitations.

Comment: ok thanks Ron thats what I was starting to think as well, I thank you very much for your help and expertise. TakeCcare and Be Well - Curt

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see your purpose in the final format so guesses aren't too likely to be correct. Nonetheless, I'll make my best guess and think your purpose is to show the difference in time as a portion of the current year, as a date in the year to give a feel of a different sort than a percentage of the year would do. So I am guessing your desired outcome in the example would be "20/03/10 08:00:00"...

You could accomplish that by adding 43830 to the subtraction in A3. So the elapsed time would be relative to the start of the year. You could future-proof that by using DATEVALUE() and passing it a constructed string that finds the current year and joins "1/1/" to it.

(If that isn't the idea, you need to edit to "clarify" (i.e.:  make a mention of SOME kind just what you are looking for). A few more hours and no one will answer it even after an edit and it might get voted Closed too.)

Comment: Hi there, what I want to do ( but not for the purpose used in the example) is for instance I know the year, month, day, hour, minute and second My daughter was born and I want excel to subtract it from the current year, month, day, hour, minute and second and give me the difference in year, month, day, hour, minute and second. Is there no way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

*Since you are using Date Timestamp (Date & Time together) then you have to work with different methods. You can't us the `DATEVALUE` function because it converts a date represented as text into a proper Excel date.*

[image]

- If you want to get difference in Years, Months & Days then use this formula in cell O5:

  ```
  =DATEDIF(O3,O1,"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF(O3,O1,"YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF(O3,O1,"MD") & " Days"
  ```
- To get the total days formula is in O7:

  `=-INT(O3-O1) & " Days"`
- If you want to calculate total hours then formula in cell O9:

  `=O1-O3`
- Applied format on cell O9 is, `[h]:mm:ss`, where `[h]` evaluates data as 24 Hrs time.

---

**:Edited:**

*Through comments OP has disclosed that, the exact need is to find difference between two Date Timestamps in regard of **Years, Months, Days & Hours, Minutes, Seconds**.*

For that, I would like to suggest two possible formula.

[image]

- Formula in cell O14:

  ```
  =DATEDIF(O12,NOW(),"Y")&" Years, "&DATEDIF(O12,NOW(),"YM")&" Months, "&DATEDIF(O12,NOW(),"MD")&" Days,  "&TEXT(NOW()-O12,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins ""s"" secs""")
  ```
- Formula in cell O16:

  ```
   =INT(NOW()-O12)&" days "&TEXT(NOW()-O12,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins ""s"" secs""")
  ```

**Note:**

- I've used function `NOW()` for current Date & Time, which is editable.
- Remember function `NOW()` is volatile, so to avoid frequent change in current Date & Time, better replace `NOW()` with any `CURRENT DATE & TIME` value.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi @Curt ,, now check my post I've suggested few formula for different situations,, and I'm sure this is what you were looking for. If my post solves the issue then [You may mark it as Answer as well Up vote](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺

Comment: Plzz write your concern that why this has been down voted !!

Comment: Hi Rajesh: the formula in O5 is what I was trying to do but with the amount of HH:MM:SS as well, is there now way to do this, for instance I know the year, month, day, hour, minute and second My daughter was born and I want excel to subtract it from the current year, month, day, hour, minute and second and give me the difference in year, month, day, hour, minute and second. Is there no way to accomplish this?

Comment: I did not down vote you btw

Comment: @Curt, thanks for responding me,,  Now check Edited part of my post, solves the issue.

Comment: @ Rajesh Thank you so much I felt like I was going to have an aneurysm over this

Comment: I've run into a problem that formula is so close to perfect, the issue is when using our original cells from your example if the Date/Time in O1=25-11-2020 03:30:00 AM instead of PM it yields a result one day too many

Comment: @Curt,,  if you want to get 03:30 PM then you have to write 15:30,, and  03:30 identifies   03:30 AM, so careful during data entry,,, the question is whether the formula is working or not,, YES  it's working 100%,,, now rememer as the data (DATE TIME value) changes the Result will also,,, first test with smallest value like for day or two difference as well few hours,, help you to understand the method !!

Comment: If I give The formula O3 The birthdate of 16-09-2020 07:30:00 AM and use a current date O1 of 11-25-2020 03:30:00 PM the result is 0yrs 2months 9days 8hrs 0min 0secs .... but if we change the the current time to 11-25-2020 03:30:00 AM the result becomes 0yrs 2months 9days 20hrs 0min 0secs that sows more time elapsed for 12 less time difference. This is an incorrect calculation of the data.

Comment: @Curt  when are 07:30:00 AM & 03:30:00 PM then Excel state forward calculates 8 Hrs,, from 07:30 AM to 03:30 PM ,, but when are 07:30:00 AM & 03:30:00 AM then Excel starts in revers order counts 03:30:00 AM to 03:30:00 PM ,, is 12 Hrs,, and now is as previous since 03:30:00 PM is after 07:30:00 AM then here Excel count 8 Hrs becomes 12+8 = 20 Hrs.  If you are expecting Excel to return 04 Hrs then you have to flip the formula which is not suitable.

Comment: @Curt,, to  get correct value subtract 16-09-2020 07:30:00 AM from Current Date & Time,, find correct Age  in terms of Years, Months & Days and Hrs, Minutes !!

Comment: actually I'm not concerned about the hours as that calculation is correct, the issue is the when changed to 3:30:00 AM in the example I mentioned last. the hours are fine but the result should read 0yrs 2months 8days 20hrs 0min 0secs not 0yrs 2months 9days 20hrs 0min 0secs, It needs to know that in the case that when subtracting in the opposite direction it needs to subtract 1 day from the day result.